# Verify user bank just for activating account using stripe

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, stripe-payments

I am using NodeJS and ExpressJS

How can I implement an account verification using stripe? Is this possible? I just want to verify that that user has a bank account but I don't want to charge them. What details can I obtain from this verification? This is just because I want to filter scammers on my platform and this verification will definitely make them think twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can verify the account using following API:

> A customer's bank account must first be verified before it can be charged. Stripe supports instant verification using Plaid for many of the most popular banks. If your customer's bank is not supported or you do not wish to integrate with Plaid, you must manually verify the customer's bank account using the API.

check this out: https://stripe.com/docs/api/customer_bank_accounts/verify

```
stripe.customers.verifySource(customerId, bankAccountId, params)
```

Example:

```
var stripe = require("stripe")("sk_test_4eC39HqLyjWDarjtT1zdp7dc");

stripe.customers.verifySource(
  "cus_DsJV8TIcCJGSym",
  "ba_1DQVjc2eZvKYlo2COqxnGt4h",
  {
    amounts: [32, 45]
  },
  function(err, bankAccount) {
});
```

Response:

```
{
  "id": "ba_1DQVjc2eZvKYlo2COqxnGt4h",
  "object": "bank_account",
  "account_holder_name": "Anthony Anderson",
  "account_holder_type": "individual",
  "bank_name": "STRIPE TEST BANK",
  "country": "US",
  "currency": "usd",
  "customer": "cus_DsJV8TIcCJGSym",
  "fingerprint": "1JWtPxqbdX5Gamtc",
  "last4": "6789",
  "metadata": {
  },
  "routing_number": "110000000",
  "status": "new",
  "name": "Jenny Rosen"
}
```

You need to create customer and bank account on stripe using stripe token.

**CREATE CUSTOMER:**
https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/create

**CREATE BANK ACCOUNT:** https://stripe.com/docs/api/customer_bank_accounts/create

Comment: That looks great! I had a look at the pricing, what 100 items mean? 100 checks?

Comment: I did not fully understand what is "cus_DsJV8TIcCJGSym" and "ba_1DQVjc2eZvKYlo2COqxnGt4h" where do I get those tokens?

Comment: `cust_xxx` are the ids of customers in stripe system 
https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/object
just like a primary key in your own database which you can use to query Stripe API to get details from. You can list all your customers and find the customer you would like to verify https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/list

similar to `ba_xxx`, basically it is a bank account https://stripe.com/docs/api/customer_bank_accounts/object when you add one back account to the customer

Comment: You need to create customer and bank account on stripe using stripe token. CREATE CUSTOMER:
https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/create    CREATE BANK ACCOUNT: https://stripe.com/docs/api/customer_bank_accounts/create

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. And the details from the customer how can I get them to create the objects? Basically, in my current code on the page at scripts I have a handler and when is submitting the page it opens the handler and if the payment is made it submits the form.